# "Reverse" percentage difference

Tags: percentages

Using the percentage difference formula, explained [here](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-calculate-percent-difference), with the numbers $1$ and $1.5$, I have a result of $40\%$.

So, if i have a $100$ value, how can I find two numbers with a formula that add up to $100$ with the same $40\%$ percentage difference? For example, $60$ and $40$ have a difference of $40\%$ and $60 + 40 = 100$

i.g., for $4$ and $16$: $\frac{|4-16|}{(4+16)/2} * 100 = 120\% $, I would need two values that $x + y = 100$ and  $\frac{|x-y|}{(x+y)/2} * 100 = 120\% $

[Here](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage-difference) is a useful and simple calculator for percentage difference.

This is my first question and I'm not very good at math or English, so I'm sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: I'm unclear about what formula you're using. 1.5 is 50 percent more than 1.0 but 1.0 is 33.3333... percent less than 1.5. In neither case do you see 40 percent, so how are you getting that?

Comment: @Deepak The "difference percentage formula" the OP is using is stated as being $\frac{|x-y|}{(x+y)/2}$. I'm not clear on how & where this formula might be used, but with $x = 1$ and $y = 1.5$ it gives a result of $\frac{.5}{1.25} = 40\%$.

Comment: "It is used to measure the difference between two related values and is expressed as a percentage. For example, you can compare the price of a laptop this year versus the price of a laptop from last year.". From: https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-calculate-percent-difference

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks and  thanks to OP for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your question in a general manner, first note there's the required condition

$$x + y = 100 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since your equations are symmetric in $x$ and $y$, then WLOG have $x \ge y \implies \lvert x - y \rvert = x - y$. Next, using $120\% = \frac{120}{100} = 1.2$ gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{x - y}{(x + y)/2} & = 1.2 \\
\frac{x - y}{100/2} & = 1.2 \\
x - y & = 1.2(50) \\
x - y & = 60
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Now, adding \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A} results in

$$2x = 160 \implies x = 80 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Using this in \eqref{eq1A} then gives

$$80 + y = 100 \implies y = 20 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

---

Since you already have that $4$ and $16$ give the required difference percentage, here is a bit shorter and easier way to solve the problem. Note that for any $c \neq 0$, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert cx - cy \rvert}{(cx + cy)/2} & = \frac{c\lvert x - y \rvert}{c(x + y)/2} \\
& = \frac{\lvert x - y \rvert}{(x + y)/2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

i.e., multiplying both $x$ and $y$ by $c$ (and, thus, the sum of them) results in the same value difference percentage. Thus, since $4 + 16 = 20$ and $\frac{100}{20} = 5$, we can use $c = 5$ to directly get that the values of $x$ and $y$ are $4 \times 5 = 20$ and $16 \times 5 = 80$.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I actually know what "percentage difference" means (it was a term I had not heard used in that way before), I can help answer the OP's question, and maybe also pose and answer a related question.  This might help the OP or anyone else who happens to be working with this sort of thing.

So OP's question was: given a particular percentage difference (call it $P$), and two numbers (call them $b$ for big and $s$ for small) with a known fixed total (call it $T$), can we determine what the two numbers must be?

So we can write: $\frac{b-s}{0.5T} \cdot 100 = P$ which may be rearranged to $b-s = \frac{PT}{200}$

This equation can be solved simultaneously with $b+s = T$ by first adding both to isolate $b$:

$2b = \frac{PT}{200} + T$

$b = \frac T{400}(200+P)$

and then subtracting one from the other to isolate $s$. By analogous steps we end up with:

$s = \frac T{400}(200-P)$

Now we have fairly neat expressions for both the numbers. The OP can use these expressions by substituting for $T$ ($100$ as per his requirement in this question) and $P$ as he sees fit.

But we can also make some interesting observations from the form of the expressions. Note that if we require both numbers to be non-negative, we require $P \leq 200$. If we need both numbers to be positive, we need $P < 200$. Otherwise, the smaller number will necessarily be negative.

Let's go a little further. We've dealt with a fixed total ($T$). A reasonable additional question to pose would be to ask what happens if we're asked to deal with a fixed difference ($D$). In other words, what should $b$ and $s$ be to arrive at a particular $P$ given a particular $D$?

We again start from the definition and write:

$\frac{D}{0.5(b+s)}\cdot 100 = P$ which may be rearranged to: $b+s = \frac{200D}{P}$

This can be solved simultaneously with $b-s = D$ in a similar fashion to what we did earlier to yield:

$b = \frac{D}{2P}(200 + P)$

and

$s = \frac{D}{2P}(200 - P)$

Note that we can deduce the same conclusions about the upper bound of $P$ for both numbers to be non-negative (or positive) from this set of equations.

In summary, for a fixed total $T$ and a particular percentage difference $P$:

Bigger number: $\displaystyle b = \frac T{400}(200+P)$

Smaller number: $\displaystyle s = \frac T{400}(200-P)$

And for a fixed difference $D$ and a particular percentage difference $P$:

Bigger number: $\displaystyle b = \frac{D}{2P}(200 + P)$

Smaller number: $\displaystyle s = \frac{D}{2P}(200 - P)$

I did this mainly for my own amusement, but I hope it helps someone at some point.